# It's possible to put a fragment into a RecyclerView or ListView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I wanna to show a fragment inside a RecyclerView as the first item, could I do this?

Comment: you can add a header to the recyclerview or listview

Comment: @MalekHijazi It seems that there's no header for recyclerview. Any example or references?

Comment: yes it is possible you have to do it in your adapter. if you still havent figured it out let me know to point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but i think it is possible.
When you create a `row_layout.xml` for your `RecyclerView` or `ListView`, instead of adding any other layout inside; you should keep a fragment over there and that fragment in turn will have your `row_layout.xml`

Example:

**Your row_layout.xml**

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout="@layout/your_layout"
    android:name="packageName.className"
    tools:layout="@layout/your_layout"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_fragment" />
```

**Layout for fragment**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/your_id"
tools:context="packageName.className">
<!--Any view inside-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can I use the layoutinflater to inflate the fragment_layout.xml? I know a Fragment is different from other Views that are usually inflated.